# How forms.ModelForm get actual model in forms.py?

Tags: python, django, django-models

This is my models.py

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    ids = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ids

class Teacher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This is my forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Student, Teacher

class Rform(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']

class Tform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Teacher
        fields = '__all__'

class Istudent(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = '__all__'
```

In this forms.py every class inheritance forms.ModelForm we are not declare model name in each class but every class show rightly model field in every form how?

Comment: The model name and fields to use are declared in the `class Meta`.

Answer (score 2):

Django provides a helper class that lets you create a Form class from a Django model. You can create a form using django.contrib.auth.forms that django gives you and u can create your form using model and if u are using model, the django gives ModelForm that relate to the Model and its feild.
If You not get it what i want to describe than plzz checkout this link

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/modelforms/